# writeRaster to netCDF with more than one variable?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, r-raster, netcdf4

Can you use the writeRaster() function to write a netCDF file with multiple variables?

All variables can be read in via raster/brick/stack and indexed by varname =, so I figured you could write one similar.